# Logical Equivalences dealing with Equivalence Rules

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

When dealing with the question ->
 1. Show that ( → ) → ( → ) is logically equivalent to  →  using logical equivalence rules. Name each rule. You will get no credit for any other type of solution, such as a solution by truth table.

I understand I need to go through and use the laws, but I'm not entirely sure what I'm supposed to be doing. Am I supposed to go through and alter the p & q to fit into the other laws? (Such as De Morgan, Communtative, ect)

Such as, ≡ ¬ (¬p ∨ q) ∨ (¬q∨p) [DeMorgan law? P.s I don't know if I did this one right]

Comment: What do you need to show?  I only see a bunch of conditionals ... no variables. Please edit your post if you want any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

As stated your question is: **Show that ( → ) → ( → ) is logically equivalent to  →  using logical equivalence rules. Name each rule. You will get no credit for any other type of solution, such as a solution by truth table.**

Here you two show equivalence of two logical statements using the rules, naming each of the rule. Also use of truth table to prove equivalence is prohibited.

Proof of equivalence:
$( → ) → ( → ) \equiv  → $

LHS:

$(p → q) → (q → p) = (\sim p  \lor  q) → (\sim q  \lor  p)$. $\quad[Def. of implication]$

$ \Rightarrow(\sim(\sim p  \lor  q)  \lor (\sim q  \lor  p)\,)$ . $\quad[Def. of implication]$

$ \Rightarrow (p\,\land  \sim q)  \lor (\sim q  \lor  p)\,)$ .   $\quad[DeMorgan's laws]$

$ \Rightarrow (∼q∨p)$ .   $\quad[Associative\,\&\,Distributive laws]$

$ \Rightarrow (∼q∨p) = (q → p)$ = RHS.     $\quad[Def. of implication]$

$\therefore LHS = RHS$.

Hence Proved.